# Zooming in datagridview reacts weird

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms: F1 and F2, both containing datagridview controls.

F1 has a datagridview control to display some entries. Double clicking on a row opens F2 to display the selected entry infos.

On F1, i have a "Datagridview Zoom In/Zoom Out" fonction w:

```
Private Sub btnZoomOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnZoomOut.Click
Dim strMsgboxNoMoreZoomOut As String = "Cant zoom out more"
Dim intActualFontSizeCell As Int16 = CShort(dtgHashtagSrchResults.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Size)
Dim intActualFontSizeHEader As Int16 = CShort(dtgHashtagSrchResults.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Size)
With Me.dtgHashtagSrchResults
   If intActualFontSizeCell < 8 Then
      MsgBox(strMsgboxNoMoreZoomOut, MsgBoxStyle.Information, strMsgBoxHashtagTitle)
   Else
     .DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Lato", intActualFontSizeCell - 1)
     .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Lato", intActualFontSizeHEader - 1)
   End If
End With
End Sub

Private Sub btnZoomIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnZoomIn.Click
Dim strMsgboxNoMoreZoomIn As String = "Cant zoom in more"
Dim intActualFontSizeCell As Int16 = CShort(dtgHashtagSrchResults.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Size)
Dim intActualFontSizeHEader As Int16 = CShort(dtgHashtagSrchResults.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Size)
With Me.dtgHashtagSrchResults
     If intActualFontSizeCell = 50 Then
        MsgBox(strMsgboxNoMoreZoomIn, MsgBoxStyle.Information, strMsgBoxHashtagTitle)
     Else
       .DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Lato", intActualFontSizeCell + 1)
       .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Lato", intActualFontSizeHEader + 1)
     End If
End With
End Sub
```

When I used this zoom in/out in F1,

- if F1 is the only form opened, the zoom In/out fonction is applied on F1
- if F1 and F2 are opened, zoom in/out fonction applied only on F2. If i close F1 and F2, reopened F1 (F1 is opened through a button on the main form of the application) then the zoom is applied to F1 and to any datagridview used in the application!

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6ll-tiTQL8

Comment: I am unable to reproduce what you describe using the posted code. Also, I am not sure I am following what you mean in the last comment you state that… _”if F1 and F2 are opened, zoom in/out fonction applied on F2 only but if i close F1 and F2, reopened F1 then the zoom is applied to F1 and to any datagridview used in the application!”_ … ? … _”reopened F1”_ … ? … so “another” form is opening F1? The part of sentence _” … applied on F2 only but if i close F1 … ”_ … ? … is there supposed to a period after _"only"_ ? In other words, that sentence does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I tried to edit my first message

Comment: As I previously commented, the posted code appears to work as expected and I am not able to reproduce what you describe. There must be something else going on that you are not providing.